# SSH Public Key Authentication only works if active session exists before

Tags: linux, ssh, kvm-virtualization, remote-access, ssh-keys

I have a rather strange problem with my SSH configuration. I set up my server with the help of a Remote Access Card and configured everything with a KVM viewer.

So while being logged into the server via the KVM Viewer I configured SSH with only pubkey and tried to login from my local laptop. It worked fine.

**If I quit the KVM Session (or logout with the user in the KVM session) I cannot login via ssh anymore (pubkey denied). SSH login only works as long as the user is somewhere still logged in.**

Any hints what the problem might be?

---

Console output for a failed login (all personal data exchanged):

`OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/mylocaluser/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 103: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 100.100.100.100 [100.100.100.100] port 12345.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/mylocaluser/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/mylocaluser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/mylocaluser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/mylocaluser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA ab:12:23:34:45:56:67:78:89:90:12:23:34:45:56:67
debug1: Host '[100.100.100.100]:12345' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/mylocaluser/.ssh/known_hosts:36
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/mylocaluser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/mylocaluser/.ssh/id_rsa2
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/mylocaluser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).`

Console output for a successfull login (only possible while "active session" exists):
`OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/mylocaluser/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 103: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 100.100.100.100 [100.100.100.100] port 12345.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/mylocaluser/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/mylocaluser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/mylocaluser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/mylocaluser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA ab:12:23:34:45:56:67:78:89:90:12:23:34:45:56:67
debug1: Host '[100.100.100.100]:12345' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/mylocaluser/.ssh/known_hosts:36
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/mylocaluser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 100.100.100.100 ([100.100.100.100]:12345).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = de_DE.UTF-8
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS`

Comment: One way this can happen is if the home directory is encrypted using `ecryptfs`. After a successful login, try typing `df .` and show us the output. If it is `ecryptfs`, I do have an answer to how it can be made to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSH Prompts for password even though private keys are available, presented to server and known to it](http://serverfault.com/questions/310827/ssh-prompts-for-password-even-though-private-keys-are-available-presented-to-se)

Comment: @kasperd Yes, the home directory is encrypted! What can I do?

Answer (score 5):

When the user's home directory is encrypted with `ecryptfs` `sshd` cannot read the `authorized_keys` file from the user's home directory before the home directory has been mounted.

During login `sshd` will use `pam` to authenticate the user, and `pam` will use the password entered by the user to mount the encrypted home directory.

This is problematic if you want to restrict `sshd` to only permit public key authentication.

However you can place an unencrypted `authorized_keys` file on the server as well. This will permit the user to login using a key, but since this does not invoke `pam`, the home directory will not be mounted, and mounting the home directory without knowing the password won't work either.

Since the unencrypted home directory gets hidden by the encrypted home directory, placing the unencrypted `authorized_keys` file in the first place can be a bit tricky. A bind mount of the underlying file system can help with that.

If for example `/home` is just a directory on the root file system, you can do as follows:

```
mkdir /mnt/rootfs
mount --bind / /mnt/rootfs
```

And then you can create `/mnt/rootfs/home/$USER/.ssh/authorized_keys`

There is more you can do. Since the encrypted and unencrypted version of `authorized_keys` are two different files, you can put different contents in them. For example the unencrypted version can invoke a script in order to mount the encrypted home directory:

```
command="/usr/local/bin/ecryptfs-mount-from-ssh" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDM1Ot12ThbTcPOGpfh7AiRqp3P4BMm3DNo4mDg7gDFPwCmM9rKRHTH0fBVSqkSGlXm84q29bckDukg7vfqkbTpbkP3e2YmTkP6p1J2SoX2QMUnBRRgL9It/ZiAfA2I4QzUrcywVvokO1F2DqcRLy5e5wKTUFfvIm6D2QfBmGbnW2Kkpn16hQyLT1ClXjFC1qXUhazePv0cAtWUCUGjRcLr/ipOphS7eOB46cGhYqtbMkKx0t93ZG4f6jM0o32cYy3RqprpZpTmCeG1gDyG+IlSLBYXYggr72iwTKsTZ9pMDTCBQ8Pb7l317TPOcJzTtDxnpgpGE3x4Vu/Ww+zhsIeT kasperd 2014 May 24
```

The important part is the `command` specified before the key. This get invoked instead of the shell. But that happens only when this particular public key is used, and only if the user's home directory is not mounted.

If the user's home directory is already mounted, this `authorized_keys` file is hidden and the encrypted version is used instead. The encrypted version of `authorized_keys` does not have the `command`, so the script to mount the home directory is not run.

So, what goes in the script. Here is my version:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

if [ $# = 1 ]
then
    PUBKEY="$(
        grep "$1" "$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys" |
            sed -e 's/.* ssh-rsa //;s/ .*//')"
    /usr/local/bin/ssh-agent-ecryptfs-decryption.py "$PUBKEY" "$1" |
        ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase "$HOME/.ecryptfs-ssh-wrapped/$1" - |
        ecryptfs-add-passphrase --fnek
fi
ecryptfs-mount-private
cd "$HOME"

if [ "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" != "" ]
then
    exec /bin/bash -c "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"
fi

exec /bin/bash -l
```

In the example above, the `authorized_keys` file is invoked without arguments, so the first `if` block is skipped. The `ecryptfs-mount-private` command will thus ask for the user's password. But this does not require `sshd` to have password authentication enabled, and thus will work on `sshd` with public key authentication only.

The next command will change to the user's encrypted home directory (until then the script would be running inside the unencrypted home directory).

The last part of the script will run the command given as argument to the `ssh` command if any, or the users login shell if no command was given.

One caveat is that this does not work with X11 forwarding, because the home directory is not available yet, when the cookie would be stored. But any other session opened while the home directory is already mounted, will be able to handle X11 forwarding.

Using `~/.ssh/rc` instead could possibly solve the X11 forwarding issue. This is something I have not looked into yet.

The first `if` block is a bit of a hack, which I came up with to allow the user's home directory to be mounted without needing a password. Instead it uses a forwarded `ssh-agent` to mount the user's home directory. That part comes with disclaimers about not having had any peer review, so trusting the cryptography in the `ssh-agent-ecryptfs-decryption.py` is entirely at your own risk.

The python script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from sys import argv
from os import environ
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(environ['SSH_AUTH_SOCK'])

def encode_int(v):
    return ('%08x' % v).decode('hex')

def encode_string(s):
    return encode_int(len(s)) + s

def encode_mpint(v):
    h = '%x' % v
    if len(h) & 1: h = '0' + h
    return ('%04x%s' % (len(h) * 4, h)).decode('hex')

key_blob = argv[1].decode('base64')
msg = 'ecryptfs-decrypt ' + argv[2]

s.send(encode_string(chr(13) +
                     encode_string(key_blob) +
                     encode_string(msg) +
                     encode_int(0)))

response = s.recv(1024)

assert response == encode_string(chr(14) + response[5:]), argv[1]

passphrase = response[-48:].encode('base64').replace('\n', '')

print passphrase
```

So how does the decryption work? First of all the argument to the script as provided by `authorized_keys` is any random value. A uuid generated with `uuidgen` could work. The shell script uses grep to find the relevant line in the `authorized_keys` file to extract the public key.

The base64 encoded public key as well as the uuid are given to the python script. The public key used is exactly the one, which the user authenticated with. The python script asks the forwarded agent for a signature on a specific message using the public key in question (because signing messages is exactly what `ssh-agent` can do). Part of the signature is then encoded with base64 to produce a password.

This password is used to decrypt an `ecryptfs` wrapped password file, but the primary file is encrypted using the user's login password. This one is encrypted with a password generated from the ssh key.

Answer (score 3):

I got so inspired by kasperd's idea yesterday that I made this:

https://github.com/bjornnorman/decryptfs-ssh

I've tried it out a little already and it seems to work brilliantly. It makes it really simple to add/remove keys for passwordless decryption of ecryptfs home folders when using SSH...

Like kasperd's original, it hasn't been exposed to a peer review by experts - but since it's on github now anyone can pitch in. :)

You still have to move your keys outside of your home folder, but with this you can at least avoid the nasty password login...

Enjoy!

Comment: You are welcome to put a GPL v3 license on the `decryptfs-ssh-agent.py` file, you got from  my post. The `disable` function in your script should `shred` the file before `rm`.

Comment: Done! Updated on github.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution but seems not to be elegant.

Since your home folder is encrypted, so just put the `authorized_keys` file in a not encrypted location.

Then you need to tell ssh where `authorized_keys` is.
In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, append:

```
Match User [your_user_name]
AuthorizedKeysFile [new_path_to_authorized_keys]
```

NOTE: Be sure to put the `Match` at the end of the file. The `Match` remains valid until the end of the file or another `Match` is met.

Now you can log in via ssh and do not need to login locally first.
But after ssh login, you need to run:

```
ecrypts-mount-private
```

and input your password to mount your home folder, and then `cd` to your home manually.